# Fastest way to read every n-th row with numpy's genfromtxt

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, genfromtxt

I read my data with numpy's genfromtxt:

```
import numpy as np
measurement = np.genfromtxt('measurementProfile2.txt', delimiter=None, dtype=None, skip_header=4, skip_footer=2, usecols=(3,0,2))
rows, columns = np.shape(measurement)
x=np.zeros((rows, 1), dtype=measurement.dtype)
x[:]=394
measurement = np.hstack((measurement, x))
np.savetxt('measurementProfileFormatted.txt',measurement)
```

this works fine. But i want only ever `5-th`, `6-th` (so `n-th`)  row in the final Output file.
According to [numpy.genfromtxt.html](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) there is no Parameter which would do that. I dont want to iterate the array. Is there a recommended way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid reading the whole array you can combine `np.genfromtxt` with `itertools.islice` to skip the rows. This is marginally faster than reading the whole array and then slicing (at least for the smaller arrays I tried).

For instance, here's the contents of `file.txt`:

```
12
34
22
17
41
28
62
71
```

Then for example:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> with open('file.txt') as f_in:
        x = np.genfromtxt(itertools.islice(f_in, 0, None, 3), dtype=int)
```

returns an array `x` with the `0`, `3` and `6` indexed elements of the above file:

```
array([12, 17, 62])
```

Comment: i like this one better than the one of @elyase. I feel it's more pythonic.

Comment: Yep, this is the right solution. I thought about it but assumed it would be slower without testing.

Comment: `genfromtxt` accepts anything that feeds it lines - a file, list of lines, generator, etc.  There are earlier SO questions that do this - pass the file through a line filter.

Comment: Many people suggest just slicing after reading, but in my case it was definitely the reading that was slow. This helped immensely!

Answer (score 0):

You must read the whole file anyways, to select the n-th element do something like:

```
>>> a = np.arange(50)
>>> a[::5]
array([ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want specific rows in the final output file then why not save only those rows instead of saving the whole 'measurement' matrix:

```css
output_rows = [5,7,11]
np.savetxt('measurementProfileFormatted.txt',measurement[output_rows,:])
```