# How to read only specific rows from a text file?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to process data stored in a text file which looks like this `test.dat`:

```
-1411.85  2.6888   -2.09945   -0.495947   0.835799   0.215353   0.695579   
-1411.72  2.82683   -0.135555   0.928033   -0.196493   -0.183131   -0.865999   
-1412.53  0.379297   -1.00048   -0.654541   -0.0906588   0.401206   0.44239   
-1409.59  -0.0794765   -2.68794   -0.84847   0.931357   -0.31156   0.552622   
-1401.63  -0.0235102   -1.05206   0.065747   -0.106863   -0.177157   -0.549252   
....
....
```

The file however is several GB and I would very much like to read it in, in small blocks of rows. I would like to use `numpy's` `loadtxt` function as this converts everything quickly to a `numpy array`. However, I have not been able to manage so far as the function seems to only offer a selection of columns like here:

```
data = np.loadtxt("test.dat", delimiter='  ', skiprows=1, usecols=range(1,7))
```

Any ideas how to achieve this? If it is not possible with `loadtxt` any other options available in `Python`?

Comment: loadtxt's fname argument can be a generator so to read small blocks of rows use a file read generator such as shown in nosklo's answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python but converted to read just a small number of lines instead of bytes.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27962976/901925 - `Fastest way to read every n-th row with numpy's genfromtxt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hpaulj pointed me in the right direction in his comment.

Using the following code works perfectly for me:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
with open('test.dat') as f_in:
    x = np.genfromtxt(itertools.islice(f_in, 1, 12, None), dtype=float)
    print x[0,:]
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org), that would be easier:

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: df = pd.read_table('test.dat', delimiter='  ', skiprows=1, usecols=range(1,7), nrows=3, header=None)

In [4]: df.values
Out[4]:
array([[ 2.82683  , -0.135555 ,  0.928033 , -0.196493 , -0.183131 ,
        -0.865999 ],
       [ 0.379297 , -1.00048  , -0.654541 , -0.0906588,  0.401206 ,
         0.44239  ],
       [-0.0794765, -2.68794  , -0.84847  ,  0.931357 , -0.31156  ,
         0.552622 ]])
```

**Edit**

If you want to read say every `k` rows, you can specify `chunksize`. For example,

```
reader = pd.read_table('test.dat', delimiter='  ', usecols=range(1,7), header=None, chunksize=2)
for chunk in reader:
    print(chunk.values)
```

Out:

```
[[ 2.6888   -2.09945  -0.495947  0.835799  0.215353  0.695579]
 [ 2.82683  -0.135555  0.928033 -0.196493 -0.183131 -0.865999]]
[[ 0.379297  -1.00048   -0.654541  -0.0906588  0.401206   0.44239  ]
 [-0.0794765 -2.68794   -0.84847    0.931357  -0.31156    0.552622 ]]
[[-0.0235102 -1.05206    0.065747  -0.106863  -0.177157  -0.549252 ]]
```

You got to handle how to store them in the for-loop as you wish. Note that in this case `reader` is a `TextFileReader`, not `DataFrame`, so you can iterate through it lazily.

You can read [this](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk) for more details.

Comment: I do not see how I would for instance read the first three and then the second three and so on. Could you explain that as well please? Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: You mean read the first three into an ndarray then the next three into another ndarray and so on?

Comment: Yes, that is what I need!

Comment: @andi That's not quite clearly stated in your question though. I didn't understand it at once either.

Comment: probably with a ```try: read_table(...) /except EOFError: break``` statement nested in an infinite while loop

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use an [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991506/iterate-an-iterator-by-chunks-of-n-in-python) recipe.

```
from itertools import izip_longest
import numpy as np


def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)


def lazy_reader(fp, nlines, sep, skiprows, usecols):
    with open(fp) as inp:
        for chunk in grouper(nlines, inp, ""):
            yield np.loadtxt(chunk, delimiter=sep, skiprows=skiprows, usecols=usecols)
```

The function returns a generator of arrays.

```
lazy_data = lazy_reader(...)
next(lazy_data)  # this will give you the next chunk
# or you can iterate 
for chunk in lazy_data:
    ...
```